# Simple Fix, Have an Error with my Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, menu

Have an issue trying to fix the errors in my Javascript syntax. Sure it is something simple and I'm over-looking but it's not sinking in. Included the HTML and CSS.

**Javascript Code:**

```
const menuIcon = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

menuIcon.AddEventListener("click", () => { 
    navbar.classList.toggle("change");
});
```

**ERROR**

line.  col.  error.

1   1.  'const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz).

2   1   'const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz).

4   38  'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6').

**CSS**

```
/*hamburger*/
.hamburger-menu{
    width:35px;
    height:30px;
    position:fixed;
    top:60px;
    right:60px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-around;
}

.line{
    width:100%;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#333;
    transition:alt 0.8s;
}

.change .line-1{
    transform:rotateZ(-405deg) translate(-8px,6px);
}

.change .line-2{
    opacity:0;
}

.change .line-3{
    transform:rotateZ(405deg) translate(-8px,-6px);
}

.nav-list{
    text-align:right;
}

.nav-items{
    list-style:none;
    margin:25px;
}

.nav-link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#eee;
    position:relative;
    padding:3px 0;
}

.nav-link::before,
.nav-link::after{
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    transform:scalex(0);
    transition:transform .5s;
}

.nav-link::after{
    bottom:0;
}

.nav-link::before{
    top:0;
}

.hav-link:hover::before,
.hav-link:hover::after{
    transform:scalex(1)
}

.navbar{
    width:550px;
    height:132px;
    background-color:#333;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:-550px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    border-radius:0 0 0 50px;
    transition: right 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.change{

    right:0;
}

/*hamburger*/
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar">
<div class="hamburger-menu">
<div class="line line-1"></div>
<div class="line line-2"></div>
<div class="line line-3"></div>
</div>
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item">
<a href="about.php?page_id=46">
About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
<a href="portfolio.php?page_id=44">
Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
<a href="blog.php?page_id=530">
Blog</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
<a href="mailto:kfrancis@kfrancisdesigns.com?Subject=Hello%20" target="_top" rel="noopener noreferrer">
Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Look in the console of your web browser, it's showing you an error. The method is `addEventListener`, not `AddEventListener`. Case is significant in JavaScript.

Comment: The errors you've listed are not from the JavaScript engine. You appear to be using some kind of lint tool that you've told to limit you to ES5 level features. It's telling you you're using features that are newer than that, and how to fix it ("use 'esversion: 6'").

Comment: this looks more like warnings then errors. do you use eslint?

Comment: yup. the google suggests that these error messages come from JSHint and are not actual JS errors. Solution 1 - show us your JSHint/eslint configuration and we'll get you some answers. If you're not using it and you see it in your IDE, what IDE is this?

Comment: First, thank everyone for your feedback. I was much appreciated.

Comment: Second, I made the changes as suggested by I'm still receiving a syntax error, through dreamweaver cs4. Yes, I use dreamweaver cs4 cause it was better than text edit and i stuck with it. :}

Answer (score 2):

You can add `/*jshint esversion: 6 */` ontop of your `.js` files to fix this issue, as this is not a JavaScript Engine error.

Furthermore, `AddEventListener` is not a JavaScript function; `addEventListener` is, as pointed by T.J. Crowder in a comment.

Comment: Thank you much. Been over-looking a lot of my coding with how much I've added over the years and need to relax, remove lines, clean up, and go back to basics.

Comment: What are you struggling with? If you are struggling with syntax or whatnot, you can always check [http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/javascript](http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/javascript).

Comment: /*jshint esversion: 6 */

const menuIcon = document.querySelector (".hamburger-menu"); const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click" , () => { navbar.classList.toggle("change"); })

Comment: the styntax error shows up in "menuIcon.addEverntListener("click" , () => {" driving me bonkers cause its a simple code for a menu and I can't find the proper solution.